# Scraping: scraped links - now unable to scrape and dump html files into a folder

Tags: python, html, selenium, for-loop, nested-loops

Using Python, Selenium, Sublime and Firefox: I am scraping the links off of this website and would like to save the scraped pages (as html files) into a folder. However, I have been working for days on trying to get the body of these html files to dump into a dropbox folder. The problem is 1) saving the html files and 2) saving them to a dropbox folder (or any folder).

I have successfully written code that will perform a search, then scrape the links off of a series of webpages. The following code works well for that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import csv
import pickle
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception('Last Resort!')

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,handler)

def isReady(browser):
    return browser.execute_script("return document.readyState")=="complete"

def waitUntilReady(browser):
    if not isReady(browser):
        waitUntilReady(browser)

def waitUntilReadyBreak(browser_b,url,counter):
    try:
        signal.alarm(counter)
        waitUntilReady(browser_b)
        signal.alarm(0)
    except Exception,e:
        print e
        signal.alarm(0)
        browser_b.close()
        browser_b = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser_b.get(url)
        waitUntilReadyBreak(browser_b,url,counter)
    return browser_b

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
thisurl = 'http://www.usprwire.com/cgi-bin/news/search.cgi'
browser.get(thisurl)
waitUntilReady(browser)
numarticles = 0
elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "query")))
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("query")
elem.send_keys('"test"')
form = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/font/input[2]").click()

nextpage = False
all_newproduct_links = []
npages = 200

for page in range(1,npages+1):

    if page == 1:

        elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        article_url = [elems.get_attribute("href")
                for elems in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category_links')]
        print page
        print article_url
        print "END_A_PAGE"

        elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('[>>]').click()
        waitUntilReady(browser)

    if page >=2 <= 200:
        # click the dots
        print page
        print page
        print "B4 LastLoop"
        elems = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "category_links")))
        elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        article_url = [elems.get_attribute("href")
                for elems in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category_links')]
        print page
        print article_url
        print "END_C_PAGE"

    # This is the part that will not work :(
    for e in elems:
        numarticles = numarticles+1
        numpages =  0
        numpages = numpages+1000
        article_url = e.get_attribute('href')
        print 'waiting'
        bodyelem.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "2")
        browser.get(article_url)
        waitUntilReady(browser)
        fw = open('/Users/My/Dropbox/MainFile/articlesdata/'+str(page)+str(numpages)+str(numarticles)+'.html','w')
        fw.write(browser.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
        fw.close()
        bodyelem2 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//body")[0]
        bodyelem2.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "1")
```

The above (`for e in elems:`) is meant to click on the page and create an html file containing the body of the scraped page. I seem to be missing something fundamental.

Any guidance at all would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating it.

There is at least one problem in this block:

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
article_url = [elems.get_attribute("href")
               for elems in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category_links')]
```

`elems` would contain a list of elements found by `find_elements_by_tag_name()`, but then, you are using the same `elems` variable in the list comprehension. As a result, when you are iterating over `elems` later, you are getting an error, since `elems` now refer to a single element and not a list.

Anyway, here is the approach I would take:

- gather all the article urls first
- iterate over the urls one by one and save the HTML source using the page url name as a filename. E.g. `_Iran_Shipping_Report_Q4_2014_is_now_available_at_Fast_Market_Research_326303.shtml` would be the article filename

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def isReady(browser):
    return browser.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"


def waitUntilReady(browser):
    if not isReady(browser):
        waitUntilReady(browser)


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.usprwire.com/cgi-bin/news/search.cgi')

# make a search
query = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "query")))
query.send_keys('"test"')
submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']")
submit.click()

# grab article urls
npages = 4
article_urls = []
for page in range(1, npages + 1):
    article_urls += [elm.get_attribute("href") for elm in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category_links')]
    browser.find_element_by_link_text('[>>]').click()

# iterate over urls and save the HTML source
for url in article_urls:
    browser.get(url)
    waitUntilReady(browser)

    title = browser.current_url.split("/")[-1]
    with open('/Users/My/Dropbox/MainFile/articlesdata/' + title, 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(browser.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you, alecxe! I have tried your suggestion and the first issue I come up against is an error message `raceback (most recent call last):
  File "stacksuggestion.py", line 38, in <module>
    with open('/Users/My/Dropbox/MainFile/articlesdata' + title, 'w') as fw:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/Users/My/Dropbox/MainFile/articlesdata_Iran_Shipping_Report_Q4_2014_is_now_available_at_Fast_Market_Research_326303.shtml'
`

Comment: Also tried switching directories (no luck). I'll keep trying--will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Fixed it: `...('Users/My/Dropbox/MainFile/articlesdata')` original code had a `/` at the end of `articlesdata`. Now I'm getting a new error: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` But the good news there is that so far your edited code is running beautifully! Thank you! I will come back with the fix (if I find one).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked. I am still working on the RuntimeError though. From what I can see, the last block of code is iterative (see: http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook006.html), so I do not understand why it is returning a recursion-based error. I'll post on that later. But thank you again!